# <cfoutput> a MySQL SUM function

Tags: sql, function, sum, coldfusion, cfquery

I understand the SQL sum function. This is the code I have:

```
<cfquery name="sum" datasource="expense_db" username = "for" password = "bar">
  SELECT sum(amount) 
  FROM expense
</cfquery>
```

How do I output the result of the query? I just want to output the SUM of the amount column

Comment: You can use an alias name for the column.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 9):

You can use an alias name for the column and use that column name in the Coldfusion code.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

```
<cfquery name="sum" datasource="expense_db" username = "for" password = "bar">
  SELECT sum(amount) AS Total 
  FROM expense
</cfquery> 

<cfoutput>#sum.Total#</cfoutput><!--- query_name.column_name --->
```

Comment: Please note that in #sum.Total#, "sum" refers to the query name, not the function.